# error with a drawer navigation in react-native :undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.props.navigation.openDrawer()')

Tags: react-native, navigation-drawer, react-navigation

I had set up a navigator drawer that works perfectly, but since this morning I have this error. I do not know where it came from. Because I did not make any changes on the drawer.
I can't use the function close drawer.

```
   <Left style={{flex :1, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
       <Icon 
              onPress={() => this.props.navigation.openDrawer()} name="menu"
              tyle={{color: 'black', marginRight: 15,}} />
   </Left>
```

the error is  :

> undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.props.navigation.openDrawer()')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can Try this

```
import { DrawerActions } from 'react-navigation';

this.props.navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.closeDrawer());
this.props.navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.openDrawer());
```